# Is there a way to make the parent Link exclude some child elements?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

So I have a `Link` on each row of my list which opens up a flyout. Within that there is copy button and another button. Both of these buttons are within their own divs. How do I get the `Link` to be disabled on those two buttons?

I've tried using `pointer-events: none`, `overlay` and `z-index` but none of them have worked.

EDIT: Ok so I just realised I should add more info on this. So the `<CopyButton/>`'s  works when I used both `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` but it doesn't work with `<Button2 />`. It also messes up the pagination.

```
<Link to={`/whatever?id=abcme`} onClick={() => loadFlyout()}>
  <div>
    // Second column
  </div>

  <div>
    // Third column
  </div>

  <div className={styles.id}>
    <span>Text</span>
    <span>
        <CopyButton/> 
    </span>
  </div>

  <div>
    // Fifth column
  </div>

  <div>
      <Button2/>
  </div>
</Link>
```

Clicking on `<Button2 />` and `<CopyButton />` both do their individual onClick events but also brings up the flyout.

Not really sure if what I'm trying to do is possible or not and if any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: event bubble and capture ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture

Comment: have you tried to prevent default in your click handler ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stopPropagation` is what you're after. It prevents the click event from bubbling up the chain (from child to parent).

```
button.onclick = function(event) {
    // do stuff
    event.stopPropagation();
};
```

Answer (score 4):

In your click handler you have to do event prevent default or stop propagation depends on how you want the event to react:

> onClick(e) A custom handler for the click event. Works just like a
>   handler on an  tag - calling e.preventDefault() will prevent the
>   transition from firing, while e.stopPropagation() will prevent the
>   event from bubbling.

https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html

Comment: So a combination of the preventDefault and the stopPropagation worked for ```<CopyButton />``` but doesn't work for ```<Button2 /> for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `e.stopPropagation()`.

The `stopPropagation()` method allows you to prevent propagation of the current event.

```
childOnclick1 = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert("child clicked");
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qe7pme)

Answer (score 0):

`stopPropagation()` didn't work for me, so I used `preventDefault()` instead.

Comment: any reason why this make the change?

Comment: @niektuytel I honestly don't remember